Regex in .bashrc to colorize specific folder names
I know similar Qs have been asked before, but I've not found the specifics for my question.
I would like all folders matching 'dev' to have a highlight color in my prompt.
billy@www ~folder/dev>

should turn 'dev' green, for example.
Is there a simple regex that will do this?

of all the similar Qs you've reviewed there must have been some that came close to what you want? consider updating the question with what you've tried so far and the (negative) results

are you looking for an exact word match or would you also match on dev2 and nodev?

couple options that come to mind: PS1 that's defined as a conditional subprocess or PROMPT_COMMAND that sets PS1 based on a conditional; this answer shows both approaches that should be easily modified to add a color (you do know what the PS1 should look like if you had to manually set it for both scenarios, right?)

Thanks all - this stuff is pretty Greek to me. Could not follow the linked answer. But yes, just want a way to match an exact string, i.e., 'dev' or 'prod'.

consider updating the question with your current PS1 definition; this would give us a base to start from

Start with the ANSI formatting code that makes regular text green (32) and maybe also bold (1):
printf '\e[32mHello\e[m \e[1;32mHello\e[m\n'

The basic 8 colors are 30-32, with their bright versions at 90-92, and the 1 being "strong" i.e. "either bold and/or bright" (actual effect varies between terminals).
Find some command that would do the actual regex match to add those formatting codes around the specified words:
echo "$PWD" | sed $'s/dev/\e[32m&\e[m/g'

echo "$PWD" | perl -pe 's/dev/\e[32m$&\e[m/g'

perl -M Cwd -e 'print cwd() =~ s/dev/\e[32m$&\e[m/gr;'

& replacement in sed (and $& in perl) means "the entire match", which might be \0 in some other regex tools. (Also, in the first case, sed itself won't expand \e to the ESC character, so $'...' quoting is used to make the shell do that beforehand.)
Extending the regex to match multiple words and/or adding "word boundary" regex delimiters is left as an exercise to the reader.
This could be done in pure Bash, using its ${var//old/new} substitution without a regex, as long as you only have a few matches – but it doesn't have a good way to match word boundaries, only workarounds:
echo "${PWD//dev/$'\e[32mdev\e[m'}"

(...or using [[ $PWD =~ ... ]] and ${BASH_REMATCH}, though it has no actual "replace" operation so the only way I could figure out would only highlight the 1st match, instead of all of them.)
Put the command in a Bash function, and at the same time, make sure to wrap each formatting code with \x01 and \x02 – necessary to tell Bash which parts of the output are invisible as it needs to know this in order to correctly calculate the "visible width" of the prompt.
mypwd() {
    sed $'s/dev/\x01\e[32m\x02&\x01\e[m\x02/g' <<< "$PWD"
}

mypwd() {
    echo "${PWD//dev/$'\x01\e[32m\x02dev\x01\e[m\x02}"
}

Call the function from the shell's PS1, making sure to quote or escape the substitution so that it doesn't get expanded at assign time – Bash will do a second expansion pass when displaying the prompt:
PS1='\u@\h $(mypwd)> '

PS1="\\u@\\h \$(mypwd)> "

If you also want to regain the ~ substitution, do that somewhere in the mypwd function – either as shell code or as Perl code.
mypwd() {
    local xpwd=${PWD/#"$HOME/"/"~/"}
    sed $'s/dev/\x01\e[32m\x02&\x01\e[m\x02/g' <<< "$xpwd"
}

As before, the shell's ${var/old/new} is used to do an exact-string replacement for $HOME/ with ~/ since that's easier than properly placing a path as part of a regex. (In this case ${var/#old/new} matches only at the beginning.)
